# Why does a browser display an invalid version of a JSP page and another don't

Tags: jsp, web, browser

### The Context

The homepage of the java application I am working on displays a panel of button. Each one for a specific unit of the application.

Those buttons are disabled serverside wether or not its unit is (boolean stored in database).

The JSP page creates a bean and calls a static method from the service to retrive the booleans and to disable or not the buttons :

`<jsp:useBean id="modules" class="appli.dto.ModulesDto" scope="session" />`
   `${ AppliService:getModulesDto(sessionScope.modules) }`

One of these units disables/enables the others (sets boolean values in database)

The JSP generates and send the HTML homepage on request (calling/refreshing page), all is working fine there.

---

### The Problem

In the unit toggling the others, to validate the changes triggers a synchronious saving new values call, displays an alert() then redirects to the homepage.

**Expactations :**
After redirection, the homepage toggles the buttons, according to the updated database.

Then the behaviour depends of the webbrowser.
**NB** : IE and FireFox versions are demanded. The issue cannot be resolved by updating them

**IE 11** : On redirection, every units, except for the administrative one
**FF ESR 38.5.1** : Displays the previous page :

- *On first change* : displays the starting homepage
- *On successive changes* : displays the page which should have been displayed after th previous change (as if FF always lags a step )

**Google Chrome 53.0.2785.116** : Displays the expected content

*On refresh*, each browser displays the expected content.

**Question** :
The browsers clearly behave specifically each other.
Why do they do and how prevent the unexpected behaviour of IE and FF?

---

### What i have tried

**Adding "no cache" meta tags.**
I added the following tags as recommanded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

But i did not notice any change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making sure a web page is not cached, across all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, Try changing Internet options setting on IE.
General=>Setting=>Temporary Internet Files
Select, Every time I visit the webpage radio button.
Click OK to close the Settings dialog.
Click OK to close the Internet Options dialog.

Comment: I tried : it gives IE the same behaviour than FF (and sometimes disable every units)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this first in controller ( servlet or portlet) level**

it is removing bfcache when browser back and forward by adding cache control to response

```
response.setProperty("cache-control", "max-age=0,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
response.setProperty("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
response.setProperty("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
```

or **html tags**

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

reference:

[How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)